# Custom template kendo grid - call same observable

Tags: angular

I have 2 custom templates for my **kendo-grid**. Each template need the same observable.
Is there a way to avoid to make the same call ?

```
      <ng-template appGridCustomCol let-dataItem name="lastControlName">
        <span *ngIf="dataItem.lastControl$ | async as ctrl">{{ ctrl?.nomtype }}</span>
     </ng-template>
     <ng-template appGridCustomCol let-dataItem name="lastControlDate">
      <span *ngIf="dataItem.lastControl$ | async as ctrl">{{ ctrl?.controlDate | kendoDate:'g' }}</span>
     </ng-template>
```

Thank you

Comment: Seems to me like you'd be better of subscribing to the observable in your component and assigning the result to a public property... in the same call you can set a boolean to indicate loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply wrap the templates in an `*ngIf` and assign the value of the `Observable`

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="dataItem.lastControl$ | async as ctrl">

    <!-- Other Code Here -->

   <ng-template appGridCustomCol let-dataItem name="lastControlName">
     <span>{{ ctrl?.nomtype }}</span>
   </ng-template>
   <ng-template appGridCustomCol let-dataItem name="lastControlDate">
     <span>{{ ctrl?.controlDate | kendoDate:'g' }}</span>
   </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```